# Volkswagen tiguan 2011 ignition problem and sound

Tags: electrical, vw, ignition

When i start my vw tiguan after hours of rest, the rpm goes up to 2.2 (normally it was going to 1.2 approx) then goes down to 1.2 while making noise and crops as if it was turning on and off within seconds. This happened to me one month ago so i went to the workshop and they replaced the fuel injectors, the fuel pump and the battery. And before that i have changes 4 spark plugs and 2 coils.

I am feeling that a cylinder is not firing correctly and it might be that i have to change the two remaining coils.

I don’t know if this can be insightful but three says ago the right side lights’ fuse burned and I replaced it so I don’t know if i have an electrical problem or if the two problems and independent since the first problem increased and the check engine lighted when the second problem occurred and the rpm was still at 0 when turned the vehicle until i pressed the speed pedal.

Please help me and thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!